# Expand centered div to top and bottom on hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I´ve got a problem with a hover effect I´m trying to achieve. I got 3 centered div´s next to each other. When I hover over one of them I want that div to expand to the bottom and top and reveal more content. Anyone knows how this is possible with CSS and/or jQuery? Heres an image of what I´m trying to do.

Hover animation
http://i62.tinypic.com/ek511t.png

http://www.7daysinhavana.com/ did that effect to the width of an element. But looking in their css code revealed that they were working with multiple background images.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: please post, what you got so far. best would be, to provide a fiddle.

Comment: Oh sorry. I just setup a simple fiddle which will indicate the problem. Thanks for the fast reply! http://jsfiddle.net/Pascal1712/MYpzD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what exactly is the problem. But I guess you wanna display you hover-boxes a bit more centered over the navigation bar. So is this what you are looking for?:

http://jsfiddle.net/MYpzD/3/

I modified your css:

```
#container{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;

   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

.leistungen{
    .leistung{
        width: 33.33%;
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        background-color: #323a98;
        color: #fff;
        .infos{
            display:none;
        }
        &:hover{
            height: 100%;
            .infos{
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
                top:-30px;
                left:-50px;
                background-color:#323a98;
                z-index:10;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I gave the hover boxes an absolute position and the parent div a relative, so I could add negative distances to move them a bit up and left. I had to give them a backgroundcolor too and a z-index to hide what's under the hover boxes.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/MYpzD/4/
In this fiddle a new width and a border and a padding for the text is added.

Comment: It´s not exactly what I wanted but a nice solution. I got another picture which makes it a bit clearer I think. http://i60.tinypic.com/25yyarm.jpg  -  The hover effect should fill out the whole height of the viewport with a nice animation to the top and bottom.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I did. Check my edit pls ;)

Comment: So, did it work? I mean you could set any width, height,left or top amount of pixels you want and if the first or last hover box is not fully visible on your site you just could add .infos:first-child{left:0} or .infos:last-child{left:<width of your hover box>}

Comment: I tried your fiddle but didn´t get it working the way I wanted.Sorry. I set up another fiddle where the height of the viewport (html,body) is 100%. This is exactly what I want, expanding the div to 100% of the viewport. The only problem is that the divs should not be on top of the screen and expand to the bottom, but rather in the middle and the hovered div should expand not only to the bottom but also to the top http://jsfiddle.net/Pascal1712/YwK9n/ Any chance to get this working  with CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. It was just the top:0; that I had to add on the hover?! :D - Oh god, sorry for the trouble ;)

Comment: yeah and the top 40% for the not hover full. If you wanna try it with the text staying centered you could workout this: http://jsfiddle.net/YwK9n/2/ P.S.: Please accept the answer if it was helpful